# Java android recyclerview не отображает данные

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

Убил пару часов, но не нашел причину. Помогите разобраться.
Приложение запускается, но без отображения данных.

Класс адаптера:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Value> values;

    MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Value> values){
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.movie_list_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new MovieViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieViewHolder movieViewHolder, int i) {

        Value value = values.get(i);
        Picasso.get().load(value.getImage()).into(movieViewHolder.image);
        movieViewHolder.title.setText(value.getTitle());
        movieViewHolder.year.setText(value.getYear());
        movieViewHolder.genre.setText(Arrays.toString(value.getGenre().toArray()));
        movieViewHolder.director.setText(value.getDirector());
        movieViewHolder.description.setText(value.getDesription());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;
        TextView title;
        TextView year;
        TextView genre;
        TextView director;
        TextView description;

        public MovieViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            year = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_year);
            genre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_genre);
            director = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_director);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Value (который является POJO парсинг):

```
public class Value {

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("year")
    @Expose
    private Integer year;
    @SerializedName("genre")
    @Expose
    private List<String> genre = null;
    @SerializedName("director")
    @Expose
    private String director;
    @SerializedName("desription")
    @Expose
    private String desription;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public List<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public String getDesription() {
        return desription;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Интерфейс гет запроса:

```
public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi {
    @GET("movies")
    Call<List<Value>> getMovies();
}
```

Класс ретрофита:

```
public class NetworkService {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://demo0216585.mockable.io/";

    private static Retrofit NetworkService(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static JSONPlaceHolderApi getJSONApi() {
        return NetworkService().create(JSONPlaceHolderApi.class);
    }
}
```

Класс мейнактивити:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rc_movies);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        JSONPlaceHolderApi service = NetworkService.getJSONApi();

        Call <List<Value>> call = service.getMovies();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Value>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Value>> call, Response<List<Value>> response) {
                List<Value> data = response.body();

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    MoviesAdapter moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Value>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Лайоут мейнактивити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rc_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Лайоут элемента для ресайклавью:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_year"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_genre"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_year"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_director"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_genre"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_director"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте лист полученный вывести в лог. Что выдаст? А ещё вы проверяли запрос в postman?

Comment: @СергейБувака я забыл про логи) поставил лог, у меня срабатывает failure call. но все равно пока не понимаю почему

Comment: Поставь программу Postman, проверь запрос. Кстати не забыл ли про пермишен?